# Which filter is faster - SingleColumnValueFilter for Scan or spark filter for RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I use Hbase and Spark. I need to get filtered data from table by status (maybe 0,1,2,3). I need only that data with status = 0 - this is about 5% of all data in Hbase.

What will be faster - using filter for Scan on Hbase or using Spark filter for rdd of all data having read all Hbase data?

And why? What does it depend on?

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setFilter(new SingleColumnValueFilter(...));
JavaRDD<MyType> rdd = <get data from table with scan>
```

OR

```
JavaRDD<MyType> rdd = <get all data from table with new Scan()>
rdd.filter(r->r.getStatus()==0)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Did you get some unexpected performance figures?

Comment: No, it works both. But now I can not test big data to know it.

Comment: A small note. HBase wasn't built to support these queries. Of course they work, but they are against the philosophy of HBase. If there is a lot of data, both queries will take very long (with the supposedly shorter the one with the HBase filter, as replied below), but in general these types of queries should be avoided or a specific index to be constructed.

Answer (score 2):

Filtering by column values on the HBase side is meant to be slow, because it requires going through the entire table (how slow really depends on the data size). On the other hand, not filtering it on the HBase side means that you first have to transfer the ENTIRE table to the Spark side and then filter it via Spark, doesn't it? Considering that your target values represent only 5% of the entire data, I'd imagine this would be an overkill. Not sure what data sizes you are dealing with, but this may have significant implications on memory (on both server and client sides) and also on network traffic. With all this in mind, I'd think you are worse off with the Spark filter (which by the way isn't necessarily that fast in the first place, as far as I remember)

Comment: Different to my understanding. Interesting.

Comment: Really? If you just do a full scan with hbase-spark and filter on the client side in the RDD downstream, it will somehow propagate that back to the server and won't deliver the full table?

Comment: Ah i'm reading your link. Maybe this is specific to SHC. I need to check this out...

Comment: There are a few options over time.

Answer (score 1):

ok to get a faster scan in HBase you can try looking into FuzzyRowFilter. https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FuzzyRowFilter.html

what this type of filter do is skip rowkeys that do not match your specified pattern which in turn makes scanning faster. It takes partial patterns as well.

So in your case, your status needs to be part of the rowkey.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use DS/DF instead of RDD? as the latter will disappear over time.

See https://blog.cloudera.com/spark-hbase-dataframe-based-hbase-connector/

My take is that as predicate push down cannot be disabled using the Catalyst Optimizer - afaik - your example using a DF/DS will result in the same physical plan. So in that sense there would be no difference in performance. If one caches then we could see the disabling - see [How to prevent predicate pushdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336355/how-to-prevent-predicate-pushdown).

Now I note there are different connectors for this (over time), so may be there will be a different approach depending on what type of connector you use. We seem to have gone from a period of wanting predicate pushdown to a time in which we cannot disable it in general.

In any event, your 5% sample of the data would be for me, in general, a sign to wish for predicate pushdown.