# Spark cache and unpersist order

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, bigdata

I found similiar topic: [Understanding Spark's caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903675/understanding-sparks-caching)

but it is still not exact my question. Let's consider below snippets of code:
**OptionA:**

```
rdd1 = sc.textFile()
rdd1.cache()
rdd2 = rdd1.map().partionBy()
rdd3 = rdd1.reduceBy().map()
rdd2.cache()
rdd1.unpersist()
data = rdd2.collect()
```

**OptionB:**

```
rdd1 = sc.textFile()
rdd1.cache()
rdd2 = rdd1.map().partionBy()
rdd3 = rdd1.reduceBy().map()
rdd2.cache()
data = rdd2.collect()
rdd1.unpersist()
```

Which option should I choose to prevent recomputing of `rdd1`? At the first glance, optionA looks ok, but having in mind that operation in spark are lazy I think that doing `unpersist` before doing action on `rdd2` can result in need of recomputing `rdd1` once again. On the other hand, calling `unpersist`, as in optionB can result in no free space to cache `rdd2`. Please help me to choose which option should I use.

Answer (score 1):

Both options are strictly speaking incorrect.

The first one, as you suspect, removes caching flag, before data is actually collected.

The second one actually triggers the cache, but since you never evaluate `rdd3` cached `rdd1` is just persisted, and just after that discarded. Removing `rdd1.cache()` should actually improve performance. Also, `rdd2.cache()` seems to obsolete, since the result is never reused.

If `textFile` loads data from expensive storage, you could structure your code like this:

```
rdd1 = sc.textFile(...)
rdd1.cache()

rdd2 = rdd1.map(...).partionBy(...)
rdd3 = rdd1.reduceByKey(...).map(...)

rdd2.someAction()
rdd3.someAction()

rdd1.unpersist()
```

where `someAction` is the action you want to perform on a particular `RDD`.