# Pyspark - unpersisting parent dataframe removes also the child dataframe from the cache

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am doing something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

pdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': ['a', 'b', 'c']
})

parent_df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
parent_df.cache().count()  

child_df = parent_df.replace('c', 'x')
child_df.cache().count()

parent_df.unpersist()
```

Essentially, I want to cache the `parent_df` because in the next steps, I am doing some heavy transformations on it. Once I finish those and I get back `child_df`, I no longer need the `parent_df` and so want to release it from the cache. However, doing this unpersists also the freshly cached `child_df`!

So obviously, the questions are:

- why does this happen?
- how can I accomplish what I want (releasing `parent_df` from cache while keeping the new `child_df` in cache)?

Interestingly, opposite scenario works - i.e. if I unpersist `child_df` instead of `parent_df` on the last line, the `parent_df` would remain cached as expected while `child_df` would be released.

PS: I found a similar question here [Understanding Spark's caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903675/understanding-sparks-caching) . However, the answer for that one does not seem to work in this case, as here we are already calling an action (`.count()`) right after caching.

Comment: How did you know that unpersisting the parent, unpersisted the child as well?

Comment: I looked at the storage tab in Spark UI and both disappeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a conscious design decision based on data consistency. One possible reason for unpersisting the parent would be because you expect its source data to change. Having a parent with new data, and an apparent child using old data, can cause unexpected and inconsistent results. As such any cached children of a parent are invalidated when the parent is.

There's a little discussion in [the PR that implemented this change](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/17097) and [in this bug report after the change was introduced](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21478).

As mentioned in the second link, if you do need to persist the child you can do so by materializing it as a table using `saveAsTable`.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for - not sure I am completely on board with the reason, but good to know this is the way it is meant to work!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found a solution:

- First, my guess as to why this is happening is that the `parent_df` cache point is part of `child_df`'s lineage. I.e. even though `child_df` is using a later cache point, its DAG still contains the earlier bit from `parent_df`. Thus removing that cache point somehow affects the later cache points.
- As to how to prevent this from happening, doing the following works:

```py
import pandas as pd

pdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': ['a', 'b', 'c']
})

parent_df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
parent_df.cache().count()  

# this is the relevant line
child_df = spark.createDataFrame(parent_df.rdd, schema=parent_df.schema) 

child_df = child_df.replace('c', 'x')
child_df.cache().count()

parent_df.unpersist()
```

What happens at the relevant line (marked with comment) is that the lineage of the `child_df` is cut not to include the section corresponding to `parent_df` and starts with a "fresh RDD". Unpersisting the `parent_df` then leaves the lineage of `child_df` unaffected.

Again - even though this seem to work, I welcome more explanation/confirmation of this theory as an accepted answer!