# Spark caching in combination with multiple sources and actions

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I read a lot of articles, blog and stackoverflow posts but still can't wrap my head around how spark will cache the datasets in my specific use case involving lots of transformations  but only few read and save actions. Here's my use case in pseudo-code

```scala
val ds1 = spark.loadFromDatabase("table_1") // Action (1)
val ds2 = spark.loadFromDatabase("table_2") // Action (2)
val ds3 = spark.loadFromDatabase("table_3") // Action (3)

val intermediateDs1 = transform(ds3)
val intermediateDs2 = transform(ds1, intermediateDs1)
val intermediateDs3 = transform(ds2, intermediateDs1, intermediateDs2)

val intermediateResultDs1 = transform(intermediateDs2)
val intermediateResultDs2 = transform(intermediateDs3)

val finalResult1 = transform(intermediateResultDs1)
val finalResult2 = transform(intermediateResultDs2)

spark.writeToDatabase(finalResult1, "table_1") // Action (4)
spark.writeToDatabase(finalResult2, "table_2") // Action (5)
```

I want to achieve two things:

1. Prevent spark from loading the data from the tables more than once for performance reasons, but also because the actions will replace the table contents and therefore will lead to unexpected behavior while executing Action (5)
2. Prevent spark from executing some of the transformations multiple times for performance reasons (e.g. intermediateDs2 and intermediateDs3 depend on intermediateDs1).

So I experimented with cache() and unpersist() but I'm quite unsure on how to optimize the execution. First I thought it would be a good idea to cache the datasets which are used multiple times and unpersist them when they are not needed anymore to free up memory space.

```scala
val ds1 = spark.loadFromDatabase("table_1")
val ds2 = spark.loadFromDatabase("table_2")
val ds3 = spark.loadFromDatabase("table_3")

val intermediateDs1 = transform(ds3).cache()
val intermediateDs2 = transform(ds1, intermediateDs1).cache()
val intermediateDs3 = transform(ds2, intermediateDs1, intermediateDs2)

val intermediateResultDs1 = transform(intermediateDs2)
val intermediateResultDs2 = transform(intermediateDs3)

intermediateDs2.unpersist() // not needed anymore
intermediateDs1.unpersist() // not needed anymore

val finalResult1 = transform(intermediateResultDs1)
val finalResult2 = transform(intermediateResultDs2)

spark.writeToDatabase(finalResult1, "table_1")
spark.writeToDatabase(finalResult2, "table_2")
```

But I get the feeling that my assumptions regarding unpersist() is wrong, see [Understanding Spark's caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903675/understanding-sparks-caching)

Which datasets should be cached AND unpersisted in which order in that specific scenario to achieve these goals?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You actually did this correct. From readability I wouldn't put the cache on the same line as the assignment but I guess it doesn't matter.

Now it's important to understand Spark is lazy.  No transforms will happen until an action occurs. (the write to the database).  Spark will try not to revisit the database for data, and cache it. (If it can.)  But it will if the entire set doesn't fit in memory and that's just a reality.  I wouldn't get to hung up about it, it's better to see if works first and hits your SLA.  If it does: Great.  If it doesn't I'd look at your code to optimize first before looking at playing with memory setting, but that's a problem for another day.

You correctly cached, and unpersisted.

(As an aside.)  During development I might suggest writing the data to an output table. (Not the same table)  This will save you on time for data loads and help you check you did things correctly.  I'm not concerned about concurrency but it's likely just a better idea to not clobber your input data if you have space.